# SQLServer INSERT getdate() function using parameters

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sqlparameter, executenonquery

What is the preferred method of adding the current date/time into an SQL Server table with INSERT Command and executenonquery?  I'm expecting something like ...

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@theDate", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20)
        cmd.Parameters("@theDate").Value = "getdate()"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about...

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@theDate", SqlDbType.DateTime)
cmd.Parameters("@theDate").Value = DateTime.Now
```

Comment: That worked!  I can't mark this as the correct answer for a few more minutes, but thanks!

Comment: -1 Setting date of insertion should be handled by DB, not application.

Comment: @Tomas His question was very specific, and this answers that question.  If the date is ever anything besides the current time, then a default value in the database isn't sufficient and he'll need to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should use DateTime data type for column. Second, on that column you can use DefaultValue=getdate() constraint, so it is defined only in DB. Application do not need to insert it.

Comment: That would be convenient.  I'll check into it.

Comment: Downvoters should explain what is wrong as defined in SO policy. This is perfectly reliable and standard way of doing things, i want to know what is incorrect.

Comment: Thomas, I'm not sure what you mean.  I didn't downvote your answer.  In fact, I upvoted it, because it's informative.  MF's answer worked for me immediately.  I can't check your answer right now (though I assume it will work), because the only access I have to the database is through the aspx programs I write myself - and the database admin is on vacation.  I appreciate your response. thanks, tff.

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd.Parameters("@theDate").Value = Now()
```

Answer (score 1):

The date/time parameter is NOT needed.

Anytime the stored procedure is called, you just update the date/time field at the server level.

If you want to be able to update the date/time field to something OTHER than the current time then you can add an optional parameter on the stored procedure; this way you server can update it to getdate() when it is null, or you can pass it from the application when it needs to be a specific time.

The reason Tomas emphasized the importance of setting the time at the server level is because of time zones and other factors.

Answer (score 0):

I would look to see if you can place the text `current_timestamp` directly into the sql code, and skip the parameter entirely. If you can't, then it's time to just use DateTime.Now.